# invalid image path cfbundleicons

Tags: ios, cordova

I am  using cordova application and i will store ios ipa , but i got error when try to load to store ,error is

> ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid image path No image found at the path
>   referenced under CFBundleIconFile: 'icon.png'

I am using Visual Studio 2015 cordova CLI is 6.0.0
I removed icon.png from -Info.plist file, but doesn't work.
How can I resolve,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm using visual studio 2015 on windows and remotebuild on the mac.  Find the {projname}-Info.plist file on windows under your platforms\ios{projname} folder.  Remove these keys containing values: CFBundleIconFile and icon.png.  Build to the mac.

You can also check that its gone on the mac's copy of the plist file - it should be when you build. Would like to find a better way, but that worked for me.